# MySQL search across multiple indices

Tags: mysql, search, indexing

I've inherited a large, ugly MySQL 5.7 database and am looking to optimize some queries.

Specifically, the user wants to search 7 different `var_char` columns...in 7 different tables.

Obviously, I can join the 7 tables and filter for `LIKE '%search term%'`, but I'd love to use `MATCH...AGAINST` a `FULLTEXT` index.

I created the indices:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (origname);
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (byline);
ALTER TABLE table3 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (copyright);
ALTER TABLE table4 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (source);
ALTER TABLE table5 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (image_title);
ALTER TABLE table6 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (photo_info);
ALTER TABLE table7 ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (alt_text);
```

I tried the below but performance was terrible...is there a good way to do a full-text search across multiple tables?

```
SELECT
    MATCH(table1.name) AGAINST ('search term') as name,
    MATCH(table2.byline) AGAINST ('search term') as byline,
    MATCH(table3.copyright) AGAINST ('search term') as copyright,
    MATCH(table4.source) AGAINST ('search term') as copyright,
    MATCH(table5.image_title) AGAINST ('search term') as image_title,
    MATCH(table6.photo_info) AGAINST ('search term') as photo_info,
    MATCH(table7.alt_text) AGAINST ('search term') as alt_text
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.entity_id = table1.fid
LEFT JOIN table3 on table3.entity_id = table1.fid
LEFT JOIN table4 on table4.entity_id = table1.fid
LEFT JOIN table5 on table5.entity_id = table1.fid
LEFT JOIN table6 on table6.entity_id = table1.fid
LEFT JOIN table7 ON table7.alt_text = table1.fid
WHERE
    MATCH(table1.name) AGAINST ('search term') OR
    MATCH(table2.byline) AGAINST ('search term') OR
    MATCH(table3.copyright) AGAINST ('search term') OR
    MATCH(table4.source) AGAINST ('search term') OR
    MATCH(table5.image_title) AGAINST ('search term') OR
    MATCH(table6.photo_info) AGAINST ('search term') OR
    MATCH(table7.alt_text) AGAINST ('search term');
```

Ideally I would just use Elasticsearch / Lucene / Solr etc but let's assume for a moment I can't use any of those things, that I'm restricted to MySQL. Is there a good way to do this?

Here is the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` output:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  table1  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    557535  100 NULL    
1   SIMPLE  table2  NULL    ref entity_id   entity_id   4   mydb.table1.fid 1   100 NULL    
1   SIMPLE  table3  NULL    ref entity_id   entity_id   4   mydb.table1.fid 1   100 NULL    
1   SIMPLE  table4  NULL    ref entity_id   entity_id   4   mydb.table1.fid 1   100 NULL    
1   SIMPLE  table5  NULL    ref entity_id   entity_id   4   mydb.table1.fid 1   100 NULL    
1   SIMPLE  table6  NULL    ref entity_id   entity_id   4   mydb.table1.fid 1   100 NULL    
1   SIMPLE  table7  NULL    ALL field_file_image_alt_text_value NULL    NULL    NULL    203374  100 Using where
```

===========================================

**Answer**: Bomar's solution below is the right approach but MySQL 5.7 didn't like his syntax. I had to code it this way:

SELECT fid, scoredName AS score, origname AS "File Name", NULL AS Byline, NULL AS Copyright, NULL AS Source, NULL AS "Image title", NULL AS "Photo info", NULL AS "Alt text"

```
    SELECT fid, MATCH(origname) AGAINST ('search term') AS scoredName, origname, NULL AS N4, NULL AS N5, NULL AS N6, NULL AS N7, NULL AS N8, NULL AS N9
    FROM table1
    WHERE MATCH(origname) AGAINST ('search term')

    UNION

    SELECT entity_id, MATCH(byline) AGAINST ('search term') AS scoredByline, NULL AS N3, byline, NULL AS N5, NULL AS N6, NULL AS N7, NULL AS N8, NULL AS N9
    FROM table2   
    WHERE MATCH (byline) AGAINST ('search term')

    UNION

    SELECT entity_id, MATCH(copyright) AGAINST ('search term') AS scoredCopyright, NULL AS N3, NULL AS N4, copyright, NULL AS N6, NULL AS N7, NULL AS N8, NULL AS N9
    FROM table3
    WHERE MATCH (copyright) AGAINST ('search term')

    UNION

    SELECT entity_id, MATCH(source) AGAINST ('search term') AS scoredSource, NULL AS N3, NULL AS N4, NULL AS N5, source, NULL AS N7, NULL AS N8, NULL AS N9
    FROM table4
    WHERE MATCH (source) AGAINST ('search term')

    UNION

    SELECT entity_id, MATCH(image_title) AGAINST ('search term') AS scoredTitle, NULL AS N3, NULL AS N4, NULL AS N5, NULL AS N6, image_title, NULL AS N8, NULL AS N9
    FROM table5
    WHERE MATCH(image_title) AGAINST ('search term')

    UNION

    SELECT entity_id, MATCH(full_photo_info) AGAINST ('search term') AS scoredPhotoInfo, NULL AS N3, NULL AS N4, NULL AS N5, NULL AS N6, NULL AS N7, full_photo_info, NULL AS N9
    FROM table6
    WHERE MATCH(full_photo_info) AGAINST ('search term')

    UNION

    SELECT entity_id, MATCH(file_image_alt_text) AGAINST ('search term') as scoredaltText, NULL AS N3, NULL AS N4, NULL AS N5, NULL AS N6, NULL AS N7, NULL AS N8, file_image_alt_text
    FROM table7
    WHERE MATCH(file_image_alt_text) AGAINST ('search term')
) AS g
GROUP BY fid, score, origname, byline, copyright, source, "Image title", "Photo info", "Alt text"
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

To explain: `UNION` is just concatenating the subsequent queries into the columns set up by the first query.

Hence they all have to have the same number of columns, and that's why you see all those `NULL` values.

But you can't have two columns with the same name, so you have to alias each `NULL`.

Next up I'll probably weight the different indices by multiplying the more important ones by a constant.

Comment: This is new for me, but do you read this documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html. You need to declare FULLTEXT INDEX on the columns you going to perform the searchs.

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified -- I've already done that. Added.

Comment: Unfortunately, `OR` queries are optimized very poorly in MySQL. It looks like you should do each join separately, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: post explain extended

Comment: ok, explain extended posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OR` makes this hard for MySQL to optimize. Use separate queries that are combined with `UNION`.

This assumes that there's just one row for each `entity_id` in each of the related tables. If not, the original query returns a cross product of all matching rows, while this just returns the maximum match from each table.

```
SELECT fid, MAX(name) AS name, MAX(byline) AS byline, MAX(copyright) AS copyright, MAX(source) AS source, MAX(image_title) AS image_title, MAX(photo_info) AS photo_info, MAX(alt_text) AS alt_text
    FROM (
    SELECT fid, MATCH(name) AGAINST ('search term') as name, NULL AS byline, NULL AS copyright, NULL AS source, NULL AS image_title, NULL AS photo_info, NULL AS alt_text
    FROM table1
    WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('search term')
    UNION
    SELECT entity_id, NULL, MATCH(byline) AGAINST ('search term'), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM table2
    WHERE MATCH(byline) AGAINST ('search term')
    UNION
    SELECT entity_id, NULL, NULL, MATCH(copyright) AGAINST ('search term'), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM table3
    WHERE MATCH(copyright) AGAINST ('search term')
    UNION
    SELECT entity_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, MATCH(source) AGAINST ('search term'), NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM table4
    WHERE MATCH(source) AGAINST ('search term')
    UNION
    SELECT entity_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, MATCH(image_title) AGAINST ('search term'), NULL, NULL
    FROM table5
    WHERE MATCH(image_title) AGAINST ('search term')
    UNION
    SELECT entity_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, MATCH(photo_info) AGAINST ('search term'), NULL
    FROM table6
    WHERE MATCH(photo_info) AGAINST ('search term')
    UNION
    SELECT entity_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, MATCH(alt_text) AGAINST ('search term')
    FROM table7
    WHERE MATCH(alt_text) AGAINST ('search term')
) AS u
GROUP BY fid
```

Comment: MySQL says "#1054 - Unknown column 'byline' in 'field list'". For some reason the parent isn't seeing the byline column in the subquery, even if I alias it. Ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have all the correct table names in each subquery in the union.

Comment: What happens if you just run the subquery with all the unions, without the parent query?

Comment: Your answer is correct but MySQL just didn't like your syntax. Going to accept your answer and post my version above.

Comment: If you're going to post your own version you should put it in an Answer, not the Question.

Comment: Your version will return multiple rows for each `fid`, one for each of the tables, instead of combining them all into a single row like my version.

Comment: You need all the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. You were right though -- my original query was producing dupliicates. Just posted an updated version that does not above. Appreciate all your help. Works great

Comment: It should still be in an answer, not the question.

Answer (score 0):

Build a single table whose purpose is to do such searches.  It would have a single text column that collects all the words from the various other tables, and have an id for `JOINing` to them.

The resulting query:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM search_table AS st
    WHERE MATCH (st.txt) AGAINST (... IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    JOIN table1 USING(id)
    JOIN table2 USING(id)  -- or whatever is needed for the JOIN ON
    JOIN table3 USING(id)
    ...;
```

Granted, the requires you to populate the `search_table` whenever you populate any other table.  It does not, however, 'require' you to clean up if you delete some id.  The `JOIN` would simply not find a row in the other table.

The `txt` would be set to something like

```
INSERT INTO `search_table` (id, txt)
    VALUES (id,
            CONCAT_WS(' ', table1.origname,
                           table2.byline,
                            ... ) );
```